# Chrome pre-fetching of pages in a domain

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey, code-injection, prefetch

I read in a source that chrome, when it goes to a domain, it prefetches most of the pages that might be used for that domain. As a result of this, I'm facing a problem. I have a greasemonkey script which is to be injected in every page. But what seems to happen is that the browser injects the script for the first page in a domain and that remains when i go to another page, instead of being re-injected (which is what i would want). Any ideas on how i could achieve this behavior ??

Comment: Is that the behavior you are seeing.  Google Chrome will precache DNS entries on the page but it doesn't pro-actively go and fetch pages, Firefox used to?  Can you provide us with an example of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a case where Chrome will proactively pre-cache any page that is mentioned in the cache manifest.  This is designed for offline scenarios.  However, each page when downloaded will not be executed against any injected script, nor will it run any JS on those pages.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome will precache DNS entries on the page but it doesn't pro-actively go and fetch pages, Firefox however, does prefetch pages.